# how to use one load balancer for multiple nodes inside a cluster using Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

How can i use one Loadbalancer for multiple unique host deployments inside a cluster, and each deployment is placed in a unique node.

Lets say below is the host1-value.yaml file inside my helm chart.
If i create for second host host2-value.yaml, a new load balancer gets created.

Answer (score 1):

You have put two questions here:

1. How can i use one Loadbalancer for multiple unique host deployments inside a cluster
2. each deployment is placed in a unique node.

Question #1 can be done using an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/). This will allow a single external IP and single loadbalancer to be used for multiple services.

However, you would need to create DNS entries so the ingress controller knows which service to route the request to.

Question #2 could be interpreted in two different ways: do you mean you want all of the deployment on a specific node or do you want each pod/replica of the deployment on a different node?

Regardless you will want either `nodeSelector` (if you want to force a specific node) or pod antiaffinity (if you want to force each pod onto a different node) -- both of which can we read about [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/).